# Is there a useful relationship between connection on space coordinates and material derivative?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, vector-fields

I am referring to an important part of the question [Relationship between Connection and Material Derivative](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133219/relationship-between-connection-and-material-derivative). Here is a paste and cut of the relevant part.

> That is the directional derivative along $\mathbf{u}$ of the function $g$. On vector fields it is defined componentwise, that is, if $\mathbf{v} = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ then
>
> $$(\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{v} = ((\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla)v_1, (\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla)v_2, (\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla)v_3) = (D_{\mathbf{u}}v_1, D_{\mathbf{u}}v_2, D_{\mathbf{u}}v_3).$$
>
> But that latter thing is clearly the Covariant Derivative of $\mathbf{v}$ along $\mathbf{u}$ when we consider the Levi-Civita Connection on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the usual flat metric tensor, that is
>
> $$(\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{v} = \nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{v}.$$
>
> Now, is this conclusion right?
>
> ... I mean, I don't know that much of connections and how they can be used on Physics, but I know they are usefull. In that case, writing the material derivative in terms of a connection gives some advantage?

The answer and the comments in this cited question do not say anything about the usefulness of the relationship. I am not even sure that the relationship with the covariant derivative as presented in the  question (and in the accepted answer) is a standard view on the material derivative. If it is a standard view, where is it used?  (I mean a case where the covariant derivative is not the ordinary derivative everywhere, of course.)  I know that a similar relationship makes sense and it is very useful when we try to see how the equations of General Relativity relate to the Newtonian equations (see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/470790/227347), but then we are using four-velocity and the covariant derivative on space-time, not only on  $\mathbb{R}^3$.